# Multi Line Frame Title with Image in Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I'm wanting to try and make a header in beamer like the following (mockup from libreoffice, ignore the grid):

[image: Mockup]

I've been trying to use a number of methods, but I just can't get it right. This is where I'm at at the moment code-wise (with framebox being a pre-defined beamercolor).

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline} {
  \begin{minipage}{.7\paperwidth}
    % Section Heading
    \vspace{5mm}
    {
      \noindent\hspace{5mm}\usebeamercolor[fg]{}\insertsection
    }
    \\
    % Slide Title
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\textwidth,ht=2ex,dp=1ex,left]{framebox}%
      \hspace{5mm}\usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\insertframetitle\hspace*{2ex}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node[anchor=north east] at ([yshift=-5mm, xshift=-5mm] current page.north east) {MY LOGO HERE}
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

This code gets it roughly in the right place on most slides (it's off for the table of contents), but the rest of the text is completely shifted off the frame and is no longer visible.

**Update: Added Example Images**

Before adding tikzpicture:
[image: Before]

And after (creates a dozen of these slides):
[image: After]

Comment: Hello, could you post a compileable version of your code ?